# Python failed to build wheel for pyalsaaudio

Tags: python

I'm trying to download pyalsaaudio for python, it was working fine the latest windows 10 update. Now it says that python has failed to build wheel:

```
C:\Users\F.R.E.D.R.I.C.K>pip install pyalsaaudio
Collecting pyalsaaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/b6/44871791929d9d7e11325af0b7be711388dfeeab17147988f044a41a6d83/pyalsaaudio-0.8.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyalsaaudio
  Building wheel for pyalsaaudio (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\f.r.e.d.r.i.c.k\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FREDRI~1.K\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi58e96b\\pyalsaaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\FREDRI~1.K\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4uxyyn8k --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'alsaaudio' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\f.r.e.d.r.i.c.k\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\f.r.e.d.r.i.c.k\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcalsaaudio.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\alsaaudio.obj
  alsaaudio.c
  alsaaudio.c(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'alsa/asoundlib.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyalsaaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyalsaaudio
Failed to build pyalsaaudio
Installing collected packages: pyalsaaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyalsaaudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\f.r.e.d.r.i.c.k\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FREDRI~1.K\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi58e96b\\pyalsaaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\FREDRI~1.K\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ae2qg7ug\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'alsaaudio' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\f.r.e.d.r.i.c.k\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\f.r.e.d.r.i.c.k\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcalsaaudio.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\alsaaudio.obj
    alsaaudio.c
    alsaaudio.c(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'alsa/asoundlib.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\f.r.e.d.r.i.c.k\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FREDRI~1.K\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi58e96b\\pyalsaaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\FREDRI~1.K\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ae2qg7ug\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\FREDRI~1.K\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mi58e96b\pyalsaaudio\
```

Comment: Are you sure your module works on windows? "alsa" is the linux sound system.

Comment: yeah it works with windows. It was working great before. idk what happened